# React Native - Doesn't receive push notification when device is locked

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I'm using [zo0r/react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) with RN 0.43.

Everything is working fine as long as the device isn't locked. I've tried back and forth multiple times and I have had it working, but since I made *some* change I won't get notifications whilst the device is locked.

This is my settings:

```
PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: function(token) {
        UserStore.storeDeviceToken(token)
    },

    onNotification: function(notification) {
        if (notification) {
            PushHandler.notificationReceived(notification)
        }
    },

    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    },

    popInitialNotification: true,
    userInteraction: true,
    requestPermissions: true
})
```

Comment: Hi @Martin how did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

When sending notification from server you must provide following keys with mecessary values in motification payload

```
{
 "content_available": true,
 "priority":"high",
"show_in_foreground": true
...other_data
}
```